# How to change the hint background color and font color in the ToolTipBase class ?

Tags: python-2.7

I began to slowly learn the classes but I do not know where to change the background color hints and its font.

I tried something there, but it did not work out.
I tried to insert bg = "green" instead of "NONE", but it did not affect the program
Below is the code:

```
            from Tkinter import *

            class ToolTipBase:



                def unschedule(self):
                    id = self.id
                    self.id = None
                    if id:
                        self.button.after_cancel(id)


            class ToolTip(ToolTipBase):
                def __init__(self, button, text):
                    ToolTipBase.__init__(self, button)
                    self.text = text
                def showcontents(self):
                    ToolTipBase.showcontents(self, self.text)

            class ListboxToolTip(ToolTipBase):
                def __init__(self, button, items):
                    ToolTipBase.__init__(self, button)
                    self.items = items
                def showcontents(self):
                    listbox = Listbox(self.tipwindow, background="#ffffe0")
                    listbox.pack()
                    for item in self.items:
                        listbox.insert(END, item)

            def main():
                # Test code
                root = Tk()
                b = Button(root, text="Hello", command=root.destroy)
                b.pack()
                root.update()
                tip = ListboxToolTip(b, ["Hello", "world"])
                root.mainloop()

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                main()
```

I could not insert the whole code, the message: "your post is just a code, add something"
Thank you in advance for your help.